# Python - RGB LED Color Fading

Tags: python, interpolation, rgb, lighting

I have looked around extensively trying to find a method to fade between one color to another in Python. Most of the examples I've found are usually specific to a device or in another language which doesn't translate well.

I currently have a modified piece of code which was used to create a breathing effect which worked pretty well fading from 0 to 255 for example. What I have now sets the `from` color, say green; flickers; then sets the `to` color:

```
def colorFade(strip, colorFrom, colorTo, wait_ms=20, steps=10):
    steps = 200

    step_R = int(colorTo[0]) / steps
    step_G = int(colorTo[1]) / steps
    step_B = int(colorTo[2]) / steps
    r = int(colorFrom[0])
    g = int(colorFrom[1])
    b = int(colorFrom[2])

    for x in range(steps):
        c = Color(int(r), int(g), int(b))
        for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
            strip.setPixelColor(i, c)
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)
        r += step_R
        g += step_G
        b += step_B
```

Calling code:

```
colorFade(strip, [200, 0, 0], [0, 200, 0])
```

Comment: Try with ``steps = 200.0`` - you are probably calculating the step_R/G/B variable incorrectly due to integer division.

Comment: It’s hard to work with a question that keeps changing. Maybe take some time and make *one* edit?

Comment: The way it's currently written you're assigning `steps` in the first line of the function masking the `steps` arg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to start at `colorFrom`, and gradually step
along a straight line until you reach `colorTo`.

What this code does is start at `colorFrom`, then increment the current
color as if you were stepping from *black* to `colorTo`.

Hard to be sure without the full code, but it looks like you should
replace this:

```
step_R = int(colorTo[0]) / steps
step_G = int(colorTo[1]) / steps
step_B = int(colorTo[2]) / steps
```

with this:

```
step_R = (colorTo[0] - colorFrom[0]) / steps
step_G = (colorTo[1] - colorFrom[1]) / steps
step_B = (colorTo[2] - colorFrom[2]) / steps
```

Edit: And, as jasonharper pointed out, you may be doing integer division. Not clear what your types are. If you're using Python 2, `/` is integer division. In Python 3, it's floating point.

Comment: Nice one thanks. I had to keep the steps as an int because the library I use doesn't support floating numbers for color. It's working pretty well and smooth too

Comment: Well, you could make them floating point internally and just convert to `int` when setting colors (which the code looks like it's doing already). Might be a little smoother that way.